# Zend_Mail function not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, zend-framework

> i want send mail menually.
> Is there any othere option to send mail in magento 2.

```
$html_body = 'Test Mail';
$from = "example@gmail.com";
$nameFrom = "From Name";
$to = "example@gmail.com";
$nameTo = "To Name";

$email = new \Zend_Mail();
$email->setSubject("Email Subject"); 
$email->setBodyText($html_body);    
$email->setFrom($from, $nameFrom);
$email->addTo($to, $nameTo);
$email->send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use magento logic to send mail

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ReviewReminder/blob/d048dbf0ec436f84be89b2f497eecceb1df3a79d/Helper/Order.php#L551-L600

```
    /**
     * Send transactional email
     * @param array $vars
     * @return int
     */
    public function sendTransactionalEmail($vars = [])
    {
        $email = $vars['email'] ?? null;
        $storeId = $vars['store'] ?? Store::DISTRO_STORE_ID;


        if (empty($vars) || !$email) {
            return self::EMAIL_ERROR_PARAM;
        }


        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
                $this->getEmailTemplate($storeId) // email template
            )->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $storeId,
                ]
            )->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'firstname' => $vars['firstname'] ?? null,
                    'lastname' => $vars['lastname'] ?? null,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'items' => $vars['items'] ?? null,
                    'currency' => $vars['currency'] ?? null,
                    'helper' => $this
                ]
            )->setFrom(
                $this->getEmailIdentity($storeId) // general
            )->addTo(
                $this->escaper->escapeHtml($vars['email'] ?? null),
                $this->escaper->escapeHtml($vars['firstname'] ?? null)
            );


            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();


            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

            return self::EMAIL_SUCCESS;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
        return self::EMAIL_ERROR_EXCEPTION;
    }
```

But if you want to use Zend Mail the partial code to create a new mail message is as follows −

```
use Zend\Mail;
$mail = new Mail\Message(); 
$mail->setSubject('Zend email sample'); 
$mail->setBody('This is content of the mail message'); 
$mail->setFrom('sender@example.com', "sender-name"); 
$mail->addTo('recipient@test.com', "recipient-name");
```

Zend provides Zend\Mail\Sendmail class to send the mail message. Sendmail uses the php native mail function, mail to send the mail message and we can configure the transport layer using php configuration file.

The partial coding using Sendmail is as follow −

```
$transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail(); 
$transport->send($mail);
```

The zend-mail provides many transport layer and each may require many additional parameters such as username, password, etc

Comment: I want to send mail custom using simple mail function or zend mail function is there any other solution

Comment: You might get away with using the mail function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php depends what you are doing